# Change background color in custom Tab programmatically

Tags: android, colors, background, tabs

I'm trying to create a custom Tabs. I implemented the indicator color with 9.png with [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=dark&actionbarstyle=transparent&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=2D2D2D%2C100&secondaryColor=222%2C100&tabColor=fff%2C100&tertiaryColor=690%2C100&accentColor=f80%2C100&cabBackColor=9c0%2C100&cabHighlightColor=93c%2C100). But now I want to change the background color for each Tab programmatically. How I can do? Thank you.

**JAVA**

```
    TabWidget tw = (TabWidget)tabs.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

    View tabView = tw.getChildTabViewAt(0);
    tabView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_blanco);

    View tabView2 = tw.getChildTabViewAt(1);
    tabView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_blanco);
```

**tab_indicator_blanco.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_blanco" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_blanco" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_blanco" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_blanco" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_blanco" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_blanco" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_blanco" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_blanco" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Use `tw.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C4996C"));`

Comment: That cleared my tab indicator. I want to combine background color and tab indicator

Comment: What do you get by setting those?

Comment: It only paints my tabs of white, but the tab indicator not shows

Comment: But why you want programmatically although it can be done using custom styles

Comment: because I have 2 different styles and the background color for each tabs are differents

Comment: try setting `android:divider` in your layout!